# how to search for a value from an array

Tags: c#

I am making a blackjack game using console application and I started to make my card class but I am not sure on how to use my value set accessor to search for value using the array and then determine if the value argument is valid.

Any help would be appreciated

Here is the table I need to use

```
String[] values = {"A","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","J","Q","K"};
```

Here is my card class so far

```
class Card
{

    public enum SUIT { HEARTS, SPADES, DIAMONDS, CLUBS };

    private SUIT _suit;
    private Int32 _value;

    public Card(SUIT suit, Int32 value)
    {

        Suit = _suit;
        Value = _value;
    }

    public SUIT Suit
    {
        get
        {
            //Return member variable value
            return _suit;
        }
        set
        {

        }
    }
    //Public FirstName accessor: Pascal casing
    public Int32 Value 
    {
        get
        {
            //Return member variable value
            return _value;
        }
        set
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am having a bad time trying to undestand your question

Comment: You can try using Array.IndexOf() method. Rgds,

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Your constructor is also written wrong. You need to use `_suit = suit` vice `Suit = _suit`. You're attempting to set your properties using their backing fields instead of using the parameters passed into the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your `_value` variable to string. Also, you have to use the keyword `value` in your `set` statements:

```
public SUIT Suit
{
    get
    {
        //Return member variable value
        return _suit;
    }
    set
    {
        _suit = value;
    }
}
//Public FirstName accessor
public string Value 
{
    get
    {
        //Return member variable value
        return _value;
    }
    set
    {
         _value = value;
    }
}
```

If you want to send the index, change the name of your property to `Index`. Sounds easier! Then use

```
_value = value;
```

As Int32. When you wish to retrieve the card, you use:

```
 = values[Index];
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question try something like:

```
int index = Array.IndexOf(values, Convert.ToInt32(_value));
if(index > 0)
    _value = value;
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question you are trying to validate if the value set to your card is in your array. since there are only 13 options, and they will never change, just make an enum as you did with SUIT

```
public enum CardValue {
One, Two ..... Queen, King
}

public Card(SUIT suit, CardValue value)
{
    Suit = _suit;
    Value = _value;
}
```